# validating user input strings to execute in Javascript as safe/sanitized

Tags: javascript, math-expression-eval

I would like to give users the ability to enter formulas which will later perform calculations with a small number of variables in scope.

While use of ECMAScript's `Function` constructor to parse user input introduces plenty of potential for introducing malicious code, the counter argument is that building and executing an expression tree parser is no trivial task, adds to the size of the served script files, and would likely not be as performant as the following solution.

I am thinking about creating an architecture whereby numerical calculations can be entered by users, and the input is subsequently validated as safe (i.e. representing a simple arithmetic expression) on the server like so:

```
function isUserFunctionSafe(userInput) {
   // weight = weight in kilograms, BSA = body surface area in meters-square
   allowedVars = ['weight', 'BSA', 'age.totalYears' ]
   const varStrippedStr = allowedVars.reduce(
      (accumulator, current) => accumulator.replaceAll(current, ''),
      userInput
   )
   // This should only allow logical, comparison, ternary and arithmetic operators
   // potentially could also test with /[\p{L}_$]/u
   return !/[^\d .&|()<>=?:+*/%-]/.test(varStrippedStr)
}
```

Then the client executes the string which has previously passed the above server test like so:

```
/* formula is a string like 'age.totalYears < 12 ? BSA * 500 : weight * 10'
   anthropometry is an object with the properties:
   {
      weight: 20,
      BSA: 0.8,
      age: {
         totalYears: 5
      }
   }
*/
function execFormula(formula, anthropometry) {
   const namedArgs = Object.keys(anthropometry).concat(`"use strict";return (${formula});`)
   const parsedFunc = Function(...namedArgs)
   return parsedFunc(...Object.values(anthropometry))
}
```

my questions are:

- Is there still potential for malicious code to be executed despite passing the validation/sanitized test above?
- Does either of the regular expressions provided in the `isUserFunctionSafe` have strengths or weaknesses in eliminating any code which might execute a function or assign values to any variables in the global scope?
- Are there advantages to just doing a simple text replacement to a purely mathematical formula in the `execFormula` function above - i.e. `formula = formula.replaceAll('age.totalYears', anthropometry.age.totalYears) ...` and then simply calculating the numerical result as `Function(formula)()`
- Are there alternative approaches to this problem which are in production and safe, and what are their advantages and disadvantages?